# How to reach a modal inside a template from the coding part of the class in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

i have a component called success modal. I would like to reach a div inside this component using the code part. Any ideas how i can achieve this ?

successModal.component.html

```
<div bsModal #successModalAccessor="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-success" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="successModalAccessor.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="successModalAccessor.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

successModal.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';

    @Component({
      selector:'SuccessModal',
      templateUrl: 'successModal.component.html'
    })

    export class SuccessModalComponent {


        showSuccess(){
          //i would like to do something like successModalAccessor.show();
        }
     }
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes ng2-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution 
I used viewChild like below

```
@ViewChild('successModalAccessor') successModalElement:ModalDirective
```

And in function

```
 showSuccess(){
          this.successModalElement.show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use ViewChild

```
<div class="modal-header" #theDivThatYouWant>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="successModalAccessor.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>


inside the component

@ViewChild('theDivThatYouWant') theDivThatYouWant:ElementRef
```

theDivThatYouWant is of type of `ElementRef` in this case, which if you want the actual `html` element , you got to say :

```
  myFunctionThatNeedsThatDiv(){
     let divElement =  this.theDivThatYouWant.nativeElement;

  }
```

Comment: @ViewChild('successModal') successModalElement:ElementRef, this.successModalElement.nativeElement.show(); returns null pointer error for me.

Comment: do you want the resulting html ?  @Milad